# How to code an If Else Statement that has a condition if the 5th option in flutter is selected?

Tags: if-statement, flutter

May I ask on how can I code a statement and condition to let flutter know that the fifth option on list.generate is selected?

```
List<Answerlist> usingCollection = [
Answerlist('excellent', 'Excellent'),
Answerlist('verygood', 'Very Good'),
Answerlist('good', 'Good'),
Answerlist('fair', 'Fair'),
Answerlist('poor', 'Poor'),
];

list.generate(usingcollection.length,(int index)
{
  return GestureDetector
  (onTapUp: (detail)
  {
     if(Answerlist == //5th index is selected)
     {
       statustype = 'Poor'
     }
  }
}
```

Then on the Hero Code on flutter which is on the same dart file,, not two dart file

```
if (widget.statusType == 'Poor') {
      imgPath = 'images/sad.gif';
      msg = 'We are so sorry. What we did wrong?';
      feedbackList = [
        Feedback('Not helpful and not thoughful', false),
        Feedback('Slow and not responsive', false),
        Feedback('Support line is always busy', false),
        Feedback('Confusing', false),
        Feedback('Other', false),
      ];
    }
```

I was hoping it should show a screen like a hero style on flutter that will show this other option to indicate whats wrong why they choose this option?

Please let me know if i did something wrong thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption on Answerlist

```
class Answerlist {
   final String status;
   final String statusType;
}
```

You can do

```
list.generate(usingcollection.length,(int index)
{
  return GestureDetector
  (onTapUp: (detail)
  {
    statustype = usingcollection[index].statusType;
  }
}
```

Comment: am i not gonna put on assumption something like Answerlist{this. status, this.statustype}

Comment: and how will flutter understood that im looking for the 5th answer on the other code?,, as you may the answers are 1,excellent, 2.good,3 etc and the 5th is poor, and how does flutter will do it on your code if i may? :)

Comment: You want to generate 5 GestureDetectors with static function or what? If that's what you want, you can easily compare objects with the help of https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Comment: something like this,,i have 5 options, (A,B,C,D,E),,, the first 4 options are okay to proceed, but when they press the E, it should show additional page, like E (F,G,H,D)